# Segmentation fault error in C programming

Tags: c, cs50

Im getting a **Segmentation fault error** in this program when i just run the ./caesar command. I found that the error gets printed when i write **int length=strlen(argv[1]);** at the beginning of the code, it works fine when i place this line just before the (for loop), but i dont understand why it works fine there and not at the top of the program??

I would really appreciate the help!! Thanks in advance.

```
int main(int argc,string argv[])
{
    int s=0;
    int length=strlen(argv[1]); ##GETS ERROR

    if ( argc !=2)
    {
        printf("Usage:./caesar key\n");
        return 1;
    }
    else
    {

        int length=strlen(argv[1]); ##WORKS FINE

        for (int i = 0; i < length ; i += 1)
        {
            int c= argv[1][i];
            if (isdigit(c))
            {
                s += 1;
            }
            else
            {
                s+=0;
            }
        }
        printf("%i\n",s);
        if (length==s)
        {
            int key = atoi(argv[1]);
            printf("int:%i\n",key);
        }
        else
        {
            printf("Usage:./caesar key\n");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the command line you are using to run this? `argv[1]` requires at least one command line argument, so you shouldn't access it until after the `argc` check ensures it exists.

Comment: `int length=strlen(argv[1]); ##GETS ERROR` because you are not passing any argument to the program, the second `strlen` works fine when you pass one argument, otherwise it is not called. Notice that you don't need a second branch (`else`) since you `return 1` from the `if` clause.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your first try:

```
int length=strlen(argv[1]); ##GETS ERROR
```

This gives an error, because, there is one argument, when you call main: there is no argument with index 1. This way is unsafe, so you should handle the number of arguments first and then, parse/read/use arguments.

When it comes to your second try (where you handle argc):

```
    if (argc !=2)
    {
        printf("Usage:./caesar key\n");
        return 1;
    }
    else
    {

    int length=strlen(argv[1]); ##WORKS FINE
    .....
    }
```

You already make sure that, you have EXACTLY two arguments. Because, if not, your code exits. The problem is that, you do not test your versions of code, with the same test cases: your both and new code (with if and without) will work with two arguments; however, old one will fail if there is one argument only, whereas second will not (it will simply return from program).

Comment: No, not C++ `std::string`. CS50 `string`, which I think is just a typedef of `char*`.

Answer (score 0):

Most likely, you need to use caesar on an argument. Instead of just typing "./caesar", type "caesar blah". More importantly you should write some code to check the number of arguments. For example, you might write something like

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    if (argc < 2) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Usage: %s arg1 arg2 ...\n", argv[0]);
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    /*
    ...
    Fill in code
    ...
    */
}
```

EDIT: I feel like there's some misunderstanding happening here. If you place "int s = strlen(argv[1]);" BEFORE the snippet "if (argc != 2) ...", then the caesar program will try to call strlen on a nonexistent string, resulting in the seg fault. Essentially, ALWAYS write error checking code ("if (argc != 2) ...") FIRST before doing anything else. Additionally, there's no need for the else after "if (argc != 2) ...". I feel that it's better style to get rid of the else keyword and keep the body in the else clause.

Comment: Look closely. There *is* a check of `argc` and a usage message in the OP's code. Unfortunately, the problem reference of `argv[1]` comes *before* that check.